# No manifest attribute on install from JAR (not self-created)

Tags: java, ruby, ta-lib

I am trying to install `ta-lib` for use with a ruby gem (ta-indicator), but the jar file says there is no manifest attribute. This is a fresh Win 10 install with the most recent version of Java SE and the JDK. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Note: Most of the solutions I have seen for this issue on SO involve jars the user has created. In my case the JAR has been created by someone else [here](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html), and apparently works quite well for most people.

Note 2: `java -cp foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName` might work if I knew that information

```
C:\Users\king\Downloads>java -jar ta-lib-0.4.0.jar
no main manifest attribute, in ta-lib-0.4.0.jar  

C:\Users\king\Downloads>java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The manifest in this jar does not have an application entry point i.e there is no `Main-Class` attribute and hence the error. This is a [prerequisite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for creating an executable jar file. You could verify this fact by opening the ta-lib jar and reading manifest.mf. Given ta-lib is a library than a launchable program(GUI or interactive console), this is entirely normal to not have this attribute.

As long as you have the ta-lib-0.4.0.jar in your classpath, you could call ta-lib functions like [this](https://github.com/ishanthilina/TA-Lib-Java-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/SimpleMovingAverageExample.java).

To compile the program

```
javac -cp 'searchpath of directories/jar files separated by OS specific path separator' <sourcefiles>
```

To run the program

```
java -cp 'searchpath of directories/jar files separated by OS specific path separator' your-main-class
```

Comment: That is an excellent solution, however I am not compiling a program in java. I am attempting to install a Ruby gem

Comment: @Rilcon42 Could you tell me more about your ruby environment? Are you using JRuby or Ruby? Also, the sequence of steps you did for installing ta-indicator, ta-lib (is there a talib-ruby involved?) could be helpful.